# How to add space(s) between specific menu items in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a menu in the header that currently looks like this:

```
Home Page1 Page2 Page3 Page4 Page5 Page6 Page7
```

How can I make it look like this?

```
Home Page1 Page2 Page3 Page4 Page5                     Page6 Page7
```

Basically, the last 2 items on the menu should reside on the far right, while the rest on the left.

The theme I'm using doesn't seem to give such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide your HTML structure so here is a basic example of how to use flexbox to achieve the result using responsive design with minimal markup. Eventually, this will reach a breakpoint and you will need to use a media query to restyle it for those smaller viewports.

```css
.menu {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  list-style-type:none;
  gap:1rem;
  width:100%;
}
.menu>div:nth-of-type(7){
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div><a href="#">Home</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Page1</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Page2</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Page3</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Page4</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Page5</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Page6</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Page7</a></div>
</div>
```

To explain what is happening here... In flexbox, you have the parent and the next level of elements are it's children. The flex properties on the parent control much of what it's children will do. You can further control the parents children if necessary. In this case, we use the psuedoselector `:nth-of-type` to target the 7th child and tell it to essentially "float right" using `margin-left:auto;`

CSS Tricks has an excellent article about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/